# mysql table with gibberish values

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql file to create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `patient_namer` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `father_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `case_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
INSERT INTO `patient_namer` (`id_number`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`father_name`,`department`,`case_number`) VALUES
('205436340','טל', 'גדכדגדככדג', 'גדכגדכג', 'wowDep', '43625');
```

However, when I inspect the data in workbench I get the following in `first_name` column for example: `����`. Why is that? As far as I know `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` Collation should satisfy hebrew charset...

Comment: i ran your code and can get the correct characters when querying, perhaps it's a workbench issue - have you tried a different client?

Comment: @BigFatBaby It might worth to say, as I think now, that when I run this code on my local computer it does fine and I do see hebrew chars in workbench. However, when I run the same code in remote machine the problem occurs

Comment: i used to have that issue when my actual code files were in the wrong encoding - a bit of a shot in the dark though

Comment: @BigFatBaby How can I solve it? All I did is create `.sql` file...

Comment: can you provide some more detail on the remote execution you are trying to do? if you are executing an `.sql` file, make sure it is saved in the correct encoding (utf8 for hebrew)

Comment: Maybe you need to add `SET NAMES utf8;` at the beginning of the code?

Comment: @BigFatBaby I am using `liquibase` package with node.js.

Comment: @AlonEitan Tried, Didn't work out

Comment: @TTHER: What does a version control system (liquibase) has to to with this question ?

Comment: @BigFatBaby Just in case it matters, when I inspect the `.sql` file content in the remote machine - I do see the correct chars. (not `��`)

Comment: interesting - where is the data displayed after querying?